# Simulink, receive UDP packets wrong port width

Tags: matlab, udp, simulink

In the following picture is my Simulink Model

The Error I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve1OD.jpg)

The Port width of the receive UDP BLock should is 25 but in the error it says that the byteunpack block receives a input port width of 2. What am I doing wrong?

My settings for the blocks are the following:

receive UDP packets Block (The Ip adress is normaly filled in)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbQBB.png)

receive Block enter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3b43.jpg)

Byte Unpack Block
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfhz0.png)

-changed the portwidth to different setting in the receive UDP Block but i get the same error

-tried to implement a selector Block, still got the same error